# Can we mix Mongodb dynamic attributes to an ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongodb, mongoid, mongomapper

We are using a dynamic attributes plugin similar to this:
http://codaset.com/joelmoss/dynamic-attributes

Which allows us to store dynamic attributes in our rails model.  Those dynamic attributes are in a single database column.  We are facing performance issues because of this and I am wondering if MongoId, MongoMapper or other rails plugins will allow us to keep some attribute in ActiveRecord (keeping the  `< ActiveRecord::Base`) but store the dynamic attributes in mongodb.  We want to do this because we need to keep using MySQL for most of our existing system, but use MongoDB to store dynamic attributes about some models.

Basically this is what I am talking about:
http://www.railsinside.com/plugins/242-quickly-add-couchdb-to-existing-rails-models-with-stuffing.html

This plugin does the exact same thing using CouchDB.

Comment: I am not closing because I don't have a definitive answer.  Can MongoId or MongoMapper do this out of the box or do we need to program this ourselves.  I haven't gotten a chance to fully research MongoId & MongoMapper.  If I do I will self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason that MongoDB can't handle the same thing.

MongoMapper should implement the ActiveRecord pattern. However, Mongo also has some simple drivers for Ruby. All in all, the concept of storing dynamic attributes is a perfect use-case for MongoDB.

If you don't mind skipping "ActiveRecord" you can probably cook up your own using the basic Mongo drivers with very little work.

If you can't figure out the steps to do this, I would suggest pinging the groups (http://groups.google.com/mongodb-user/) and asking Kyle Banker directly (he's their ruby expert).

Comment: Sounds like we need to reimplement stuffing for MongoDB?  That is a reasonable answer.  I was wondering if MongoMapper or MongoId supported this mode of operation out of the box.